# How to authorize download link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I developed a software and uploaded it on my site (my site is on .net 4 and mvc3), when users register on my site can see download link and download my application.

now question is that how can i private that user without registering can download my application when the found download location in my host.

they can download application by entering download address in browsers URL.
I want to know how the file sharing servers works, for example you can not enter file address in your browser and download file.

What ways are available for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allow the user to download the file through a controller action and you should disable accessing the folder (where the download file exists) directly through browser in IIS.

This blog [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/authorizing_folders_using_routeexistingfiles) will help you.